# Conditional probability - Proof

Tags: probability

I interpret this as the statement that if A is true then B is more likely.

**I have**

$P(B \mid A) > P(B)$

Now I want to formulate and prove:

- If not-B is true, then A becomes less likely
- If not-A is true, then B becomes less likely

If I get help with the first one I am sure I will be able to do the second one myself.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try law of total probability?

Comment: The first is formulated as $P(A \mid \neg B) < P(A)$.  The second is formulated as $P(B \mid \neg A) < P(B)$.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are independent, the inequality isn't true

Answer (score 0):

What we want to show for the first is $P(A)>P(A|B^c)$. Let's start by using the law of total probability, as suggested by Alex. The law states that
$$P(A) = P(B^c)P(A|B^c)+P(B)P(A|B).$$
Now, we can solve for $P(A|B^c)$ and we get
$$P(A|B^c) = \frac{P(A)-P(B)P(A|B)}{P(B^c)}.$$
Noting that $P(B)P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B|A)$, we get
$$P(A|B^c) = \frac{P(A)-P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B^c)}.$$
Since we assumed that $P(B|A) > P(B)$ and using $P(B^c)=1-P(B)$, we get the inequality
$$P(A|B^c) = \frac{P(A)-P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B^c)} < \frac{P(A)-P(A)P(B)}{1-P(B)} = P(A)\frac{1-P(B)}{1-P(B)} = P(A).$$

For the second statement, just follow similar steps and you should get to an answer.